# Editor to handle merge conflict

Tags: diff

Is there an editor that recognizes merge conflict tags and displays the sections side by side?  Preferably something like p4merge?

```
<<<<< local
...
=========
....
>>>>> remote
```

Answer (score 0):

our tool ECMerge (http://www.elliecomputing.com) does that, it has a Open Conflict file menu which works with markers from SVN, CVS, Mercurial, Bazaar, Git and Perforce.
the menu is present also in the explorer plugins for Windows Exlorer, Nautilus, Konqueror and Thunar on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

My approach to this has been to use [KDiff3](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/) (an extremely useful tool for diff/merge) and feed it 3 files extracted with `git cat-file` and `git ls-files -u`. It is a bit of work, but then I get to know exactly what is going on. Git have added support for configuring a specific merge tool, so probably it should be possible to do the operation more simpler than

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33224759/23118) for details.